# Modifying the density of the real line

Tags: general-topology, functions, real-numbers, transformation

I am having issues trying to do something that is fairly simple. Given the interval [0,1] I need to find a function from [0,1] to [0,1] that concentrates the point density around $x=0.5$.

So for example: [0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1] would become [0, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 1]

But I am not finding a function with this property that follows a normal distribution centered at 0.5.

Comment: What do you mean by "follows a normal distribution?"

Comment: @Paul I mean that numbers concentrate around 0.5 and density decreases as you move away from it. For example the straight line y=x can be said to have a uniform distribution.

Comment: No function on $[0,1]$ will ever follow a normal distribution.  For that you need a function on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: That interval is homeomorphic to (0,1) so you can most definitely find an appropriate mapping. Regardless, the point is simply to concentrate the point density of that interval around 0.5 following a distribution that looks like a bell curve (most of the points are within an epsilon distance of 0.5)

Comment: But that homeomorphic mapping will not take a normal distribution to a normal distribution, and it will not leave $0$ or $1$ fixed.

Comment: @Paul Yes, that is true, however when I say "normal distribution" I mean something close in shape. For example no binomial distribution is actually a normal distribution since $P(X<0) = 0 $ However we often use the normal distribution to approximate a bionomial distribution with a large number of repetitions. What I need is essentially the same. It won;t be an actual normal distribution, but as long as point density concentrates around 0.5 it's not an issue.

Comment: You should drop "follows a normal distribution" from your question. It is technically incorrect and it is confusing people. Maybe better to say "I'd like the distribution to be like a bump function: unimodal and symmetric, similar to a normal distribution, though restricted to just $[0,1]$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map $[0,1]$ linearly to $[-1,1]$, apply $t \mapsto t^{2n+1}$, which pushes numbers closer to $0$, the center point, and then map back to $[0,1]$, again linearly.

Explicitly $$x \mapsto \frac12((2x-1)^{2n+1} + 1)$$

As you make $n$ larger the values become more tightly concentrated around $0$.